# Create a graph with "string" value and not numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to create a graph in Excel that takes the values from a table that describes the products with words like "low", "middle low", "middle high", "high"; and I need that on the graph appear those values.
There is a way to do that?

Thanks in advace

### EDIT

Example of data:

```
**Values**        **Rank**   
Price             Low        
Design            High
Technology        High
Robustness        Med-high
Communication     Med-low
```

And I'd like that on the graph appers just in this form; with thev alues on the x-axis and the ranks on y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would map these to a hidden field, and assign values

```
=IF(A1="low",1,IF(A1="medium",2,IF(A1="Med-high",3,IF(A1="high",4,))))
```

Then use the hidden values as your graph items,

[image]

Comment: Almost there.. I need that the value you putted on x was on y, and to put on x some things to evaluate (as: price, design, communication, ecc). In other words: the values high, low, medium and med-high have to do the work that is done by the graduated scale that is on y-axis.

Comment: Can you pose some sample data then? Put it in your question.

Comment: I got the edit :)